# Matrix Representation of Linear Transformation with Factor Modules

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^4$ and $U =\{ \vec{v} = (v1, v2, v3, v4)^T \in \mathbb{R}^4: v1 = v2, v3 = v4\}$

In Parts 1-3 of this question we show $U$ is a subspace of $V$, find a basis for $U$,which I found to be $\{(1,1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1,1)^T\}$. 
Then extending the basis of $U$ to a basis of $V$ I found as $\{(1,1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1,1)^T, (1,-1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1,-1)^T\}$.
Then we are asked to find a vasis for the factor module V/U, I found this to be $\{(1,-1,0,0)^T + U, (0,0,1,-1)^T + U\}$.

Part 4: "Write down the matrix that represents the canonical mapping $can:V \rightarrow V/U$ sending $\vec{v}$ to $\vec{v} + U$ in terms of the ordered basis ${\vec{e1}, \vec{e2}, \vec{e3}, \vec{e4} } $ of $V$, and the one you chose in 3) for $V/U$ (that is $(1,-1,0,0)^T + U, (0,0,1,-1)^T + U$). Also write the matrix representing this mapping, this time in terms of the ordered bases you chose for 2 and 3. That is in terms of $\{(1,1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1,1)^T, (1,-1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1,-1)^T\}$ and $\{(1,-1,0,0)^T + U, (0,0,1,-1)^T + U\}$.

We are given the answer to part 4 as the matrices (1/2 0 1/2 0, 0 -1/2 0 -1/2) and (0 0 1 0 , 0 0 0 1) but I can't see where these come from, I can normally do linear transformations so I  reckon I am getting confused as with it being a factor module. Can someone explain where these answers come from? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the first column of the matrix we are looking for are the coordinates of can(e1) expressed in terms of b3 and b4. 
Note that e1 = 1/2b1 + 1/2 b3. Now can maps b1 to 0+U and b3 to b3+U. So can(e1) = 1/2 (b3+U) + 0 (b4+U), so we get (1/2, 0)^T.

Comment: Please use MathJax formatting when writing answers. This makes them much, much easier to read.